# How to reboot my unresponsive Pi server remotly

Tags: networking, ssh, remote, headless, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

How, if at all possible, do I reboot my unresponsive Pi server remotely?
The server is in a house, my old family home, about 450km from where I actually live.

There's a couple of servers in the house that handle different things and the most important one that I call raspi handles the web server and a Shinobi server that handles the cameras so I can se what's going on in the house.
And that's the unresponsive server. I can login to the router, both web and ssh, and the pi server that runs Home Assistant and Motion.

Well, the router shows raspi in the list of devices connected to it. But I can't connect to the web server and that is the proxy for Shinobi so I can't reach the cameras either.
I was trying to set up another proxy in raspi's web server (Apache) to access Home Assistant but when I restarted Apache it didn't work, I had made a "bobo" with a regex expression.

Right then I was pressed for time so I logged out to fix it later.
But later I couldn't log in to raspi remotely with ssh anymore. I then logged in to the other pi server running HA with ssh and from that pi I logged in to raspi with ssh. It worked for a while but now raspi won't answer to anyone or anything, can't even ping it.

The router can still se raspi at its ip number and lists it as a connected device so maybe it's not all lost...or?
Sorry about the long rant but I thought that it might help if you know a bit of the background.

The question now is if I can reboot raspi somehow or restart raspi's sshd when I'm logged in to the other pi or the router?
Some Ethernet magic maybe :-)
Or do I have to spend the time and take a road trip of almost 900km to fix it ;-)

Comment: You need another device that can cycle the power externally, or use the RUN pins to reset it...enjoy the trip ;\

Comment: If you had activated the watchdog it should restart if unresponsive.

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks seems that I don't have any other choise than to enjoy the trip ;-D
I do have remote switches (Telldus system) for lights and such. Only one Pi server is connected to one of those switches. That switch is controlling the OctoPi server and the 3D printer.
Why I kept it on that server/printer when I was gonna be gone for around a year is one of those "what was I thinking" moments ;-)
Well, thank you for the input.

Comment: He he, "if I (only) had" is the story of my life ;-D
But thanks for the tip @Milliways. I wasn't even aware that the Pi had a wachdog. I knew that most MCU's (PIC, AVR and so on) have the watchdog so now I learned something new :-)
I activated the dog on the Pi I can still connect to so hopefully that one will not become unresponsive, thank you again.